# How to dynamically assign value to css class variable in ionic 3 component created with *ngFor

Tags: css, dynamic, ionic3

My scss code:

```
    :root {
    --star-size: 20px;
    --star-color: gray;
    --star-background: #fc0;    
  }
  
  .stars {

    --percent: calc(var(--rating) / 5 * 100%);
    
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: var(--star-size);
    font-family: Times; // make sure ★ appears correctly
    line-height: 1;
    
    &::before {
      content: '★★★★★';
      letter-spacing: 0px;
      background: linear-gradient(270deg, var(--star-background) var(--percent), var(--star-color) var(--percent));
      -webkit-background-clip: text;      
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    }
  }
```

This is my html code:

```
<ion-list no-lines>
<ion-item *ngFor="let product of products let i = index" (click)="openProductPage(product)">
  <ion-thumbnail item-left>
    <img [src]="product.images[0].src" />
  </ion-thumbnail>
  <h2> {{ product.name }} </h2>
  <p>
  <ng-container *ngIf="product.average_rating > 0">

    <span  class="stars" [style.--rating]=product.average_rating ></span>

  </ng-container>
  </p>
</ion-item>
```

How can I assign a value to the `--rating` variable of star class in html (span or div or ...)? my case is not working ( *[style.--rating]=product.average_rating* ). I also  tried :
[ngStyle]="{'--rating': product.average_rating}"; but no star appearing!

Comment: u can't pass values from js to scss... you should go around this code... ther ecould be some suggestions... maybe you could create a style shield after recieving the data using const stylesheet = document.createElement('style') then after u add the classes u have to this style elm, use document.head.appendChild(stylesheet) and then u can just give class stars but though it will not be multi in case of different records.. maybe in stylesheet you could name starts0, stars1 accoring to index and in html also call class="stars{{i}}" or...

Comment: since its not good thing to go with appended styles or even not logical to go for same class but will multi names... so you could go with ngStyle which u could know more about from this link https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/using-ngstyle-in-angular-for-dynamic-styling

Comment: Hi @MostafaHarb I know about `ngStyle`, but in my case did not work! `class="stars" [ngStyle]="{'--rating': product.average_rating}"`

Comment: the thing is that we can't pass variables from js to css... binding values can't be applied... the obly thing u can do is somthing like this:  class="stars"  [style.background]="background: linear-gradient(270deg, var(maybe alo background variable here) var(add ur percent directly here), var(add ur color directly here) var(add ur percent also here));"

Comment: but passing variables with binding is not allowed...

Answer (score 1):

I finally did it in this way:

```
    <div [ngStyle]="{
      'font-size': '16px',
      'letter-spacing': '0px',
      'font-family': 'Times', // <== make sure ★ appears correctly
      'background': 'linear-gradient(270deg, gold ' + product.average_rating/5*100 + '% , gray ' + product.average_rating/5*100 + '%)',
      '-webkit-background-clip': 'text',
      'background-clip': 'text',
      '-webkit-text-fill-color': 'transparent',
      'display': 'inline-block'
     }"> ★★★★★ </div> // <== I've added stars here! outside of css section.
```